# Can't login to Skype

Tags: skype

I can't login to skype it tells me service not available right now.  However, I can log into Skype on other devices that are connected on the same network.

I Already tried, but didn't work:

- Signing out, quitting ("Signing in..." stays even when signed out), then signing back in.
- Everything on the Skype support page for Why can't I sign in to Skype for Mac OS X?.
- Removing ~/Library/Application Support/Skype.
- Reinstalling Skype

Comment: @Allan Because i can use service on other devices.

Comment: @Allan Other devices are connected to the same network using wifi Also Skype web is working fine.

Comment: Is that device in question *connected* and you are able to browse the Internet?

Comment: @Allan yes and i can open Skype web in the browser.